# Databinding C# issue with setting and retaining data in the databind

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a databound textbox. When I change the text via the text Property it automatically updates the textbox but when closing out of the window and relaunching the databinding goes back to the old data. The text box is read only so I did one way binding. How do I fix the issue of the data not binding correctly?

Comment: can you put more details, where bound value is intended to be saved between these two sessions?

Comment: are you changing the data it is being bound to?

Comment: @sll yes it is a WPF App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be changing the underlying object data, versus the `Text` property of the `TextBox` on a read-only `TextBox` control.

If you want to continue using the `Text` property you will need to set your binding as `TwoWay`.

```
<TextBlock Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=PropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```